# Parsing xml file with special characters like &uuml; failed when I use python ElementTree

Tags: python, xml, dtd

xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<!DOCTYPE dblp SYSTEM "dblp.dtd">
<dblp>
<title>Schnelle Multiplikation von Polynomen &uuml;ber K&ouml;rpern der Charakteristik 2.</title>
</dblp>
```

And I pasrse this file with python as follows, I also have a .dtd file:

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
tree=ET.parse(r"../data/test_dblp.xml")
root=tree.getroot()

for i in range(0,9):
    print root[0][i].text
```

It reports error:

> xml.etree.ElementTree.ParseError: undefined entity '&uuml';

Comment: What is in `dblp.dtd`? Are entities like `&uuml;` defined there?

Comment: I didb't find &uuml; in .dtd file. But I do know &uuml; represent some Latin character.

Comment: `&uuml;` is a [html](https://dev.w3.org/html5/html-author/charref) entity (for `ü`), not xml, so unless the entity is declared explicitly in the dtd your xml is invalid.

Comment: All named entities in the dblp XML export are defined in the accompanying dblp.dtd file, see http://dblp.org/xml/. You have to make sure that the system-relative DTD file is found in the path of your Python script, though.

Answer (score 1):

Solved with solution from another post in this site:

```
from xml.etree.ElementTree import iterparse, XMLParser
import htmlentitydefs

class CustomEntity:
    def __getitem__(self, key):
        if key == 'umml':
            key = 'uuml' # Fix invalid entity
        return unichr(htmlentitydefs.name2codepoint[key])

parser = XMLParser()
parser.parser.UseForeignDTD(True)
parser.entity = CustomEntity()

for (event, node) in iterparse('dblp.xml', events=['start'], parser=parser):
    print node.tag
    node.clear()
```

Comment: I don't understand how that fixes anything... `if key == 'umml'`, then you set it to the value, it already equals?